# Hypergeometric function not giving a numerical value

Tags: special-functions, complex, numerical-value

I tried to run the following code:

```
Subscript[ω, i][k_, m_] := Sqrt[k^2 + m^2]
Subscript[ω, o][k_, m_] := Sqrt[k^2 + 3 m^2]
SubMinus[ω] := (Subscript[ω, o][k, m] - Subscript[ω, i][k, m])/2
SubPlus[ω] := (Subscript[ω, o][k, m] + Subscript[ω, i][k, m])/2
Subscript[χ, i][x_] := Exp[-I*Subscript[ω, i][k, m] x]*Hypergeometric2F1[I*SubPlus[ω][k, m], I*SubMinus[ω][k, m],  1 - I*Subscript[ω, i][k, m], -Exp[2 x]]
Subscript[χ, o][x_] := Exp[-I*Subscript[ω, o][k, m] x]*Hypergeometric2F1[I*SubPlus[ω][k, m], I*SubMinus[ω][k, m], 1 + I*Subscript[ω, o][k, m], -Exp[-2 x]]
f = 
  Subscript[χ, i][x]*D[Subscript[χ, o][x], x] - 
  Subscript[χ, o][x]*D[Subscript[χ, i][x], x]; 
y = Abs[f /. x -> 0]
Evaluate[y /. k -> 1 /. m -> 2]
```

What the code actually looks like:

[image]

and the output is coming out to be

[image]

but I want the result to be in $a + b\, i$ form while the official documentation of Mathematica sates that by simply using `Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x]` one should get a numerical result, but it seems to be not working here.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Since you later use `SubMinus[\[Omega]][k, m] ` , you have to define it as `SubMinus[\[Omega]][k_, m_] := ` and the same for SubPlus. With `Evaluate[y /. k -> 1 /. m -> 2] // N `  you get a numerical result.

Comment: And remember to `Clear[SubPlus, SubMinus]` first when you re-execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting the syntax a bit, and using immediate assignments instead of delayed assignments in order to get the derivative right:

```
ωi[k_, m_] = Sqrt[k^2 + m^2];
ωo[k_, m_] = Sqrt[k^2 + 3 m^2];
ωminus[k_, m_] = (ωo[k, m] - ωi[k, m])/2;
ωplus[k_, m_] = (ωo[k, m] + ωi[k, m])/2;
χi[k_, m_, x_] = Exp[-I*ωi[k, m]*x]*Hypergeometric2F1[I*ωplus[k, m],
                                                      I*ωminus[k, m],
                                                      1 - I*ωi[k, m],
                                                      -Exp[2 x]];
χo[k_, m_, x_] = Exp[-I*ωo[k, m]*x]*Hypergeometric2F1[I*ωplus[k, m],
                                                      I*ωminus[k, m],
                                                      1 + I*ωo[k, m],
                                                      -Exp[-2 x]];
f[k_, m_, x_] = χi[k, m, x]*D[χo[k, m, x], x] - χo[k, m, x]*D[χi[k, m, x], x];

f[1, 2, 0] // N

(*    -3.58742 - 1.87738 I    *)
```